# How pass annotation id?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a question, I created an annotation class to store id to further edit the waypoint. How to get the annotation id when didSelect MKMapView is called ?

This is my code:

```
@objc func longTap(sender: UIGestureRecognizer){

        if sender.state == .began {
            let locationInView = sender.location(in: mapView)
            let locationOnMap = mapView.convert(locationInView, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
            addAnnotation(location: locationOnMap, name: "Test point", id: 123456)
        }
    }
...
func addAnnotation(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String, id: Int16) {
            let annotation = WaypointsAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = location
            annotation.title = name
            annotation.id = id

            let CoordinateToDms = coordinateToDMS(latitude: annotation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: annotation.coordinate.longitude)
                annotation.subtitle = "\(CoordinateToDms.latitude) \(CoordinateToDms.longitude)"

            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)


    }

 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

        if let annotationCoordinates = view.annotation?.coordinate

        {

            annotation.id ?
            pindetaillatitude = annotationCoordinates.latitude
            pindetaillongitude = annotationCoordinates.longitude



        }
    }

class WaypointsAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation {
   var id : Int16?
}
```

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
let ann  = view.annotation as! WaypointsAnnotation
print(ann.id)
```